# Why Spring only autowired beans in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My web application which implemented by Spring can only @autowire beans in controllers, but not services. I find below description from Spring document(Section 4.9) however it's not giving answer.

only looks for annotations on beans in the same application context in which it is defined. This means that, if you put  in a WebApplicationContext for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for @Autowired beans in your controllers, and not your services. See Section 16.2, “The DispatcherServlet” for more information.

In section 16.2, neither no explain. Can anyone help me? I have my code as below.

In config package, there are 3 classes

```
public class Webapp extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{PersistConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{ "/" };
    }
}

@Configuration
public class PersistConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateRepository() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class);
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/categorybags_db");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}


@ComponentScan({"web.controller", "persistence.services"})
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/res/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

In package persistence.services, only class DBServices which I want to autowire JdbcTemplate which get null, however use the same statement in controller jdbcTemplate is not null.

```
@Repository
@Configurable
public class DBServices {

    @Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
        //some code here
}
```

Comment: This entirely depends on your configuration. We can't help you without seeing it.

Comment: @Sotirios, ok I will update my code tonight.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is the component-scan list. You can specify this in your applicationCpntext.xml file (old way) or with an Annotation on your @Configuration class (new way). If you use Annotations you can use base-packages to list package names or list ANY one class on base-classes and that will imply all the classes in that package. But regardless how you do it Spring is not finding your services because you didn't tell it to look for them.

Comment: I have my code updated, please help

Comment: Where's the code for the controller and service? Are you compiling with the AspectJ compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is in your configuration.

Check your bean definiton files and search for `<context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />` tags.

You need to specify all the packages where you put some kind of `@Component`, `@Controller` `@Service` or `@Repository`.

Comment: Does not @ComponentScan({"web.controller", "persistence.services"}) do the same job as in xml configure file?

Comment: yes, be sure you set all your component packages as parameter.